# Is there a more simple and fool proof way using subprocess.Popen() to make a Powershell hash table piped into Python as a string a dataframe?

Tags: python, powershell, dataframe, hashtable

Here is what the Write-Output string from Powershell via subprocess.Popen()  looks like printed:

[image]

Here is what the Write-Output string from Powershell via subprocess.Popen()  looks like raw:
[image]

Here is my desired outcome:

[image]

Here is my code:

```
 # 5 Exceute powershell script from the command line
#universal_newlines=True makes it so that data is piped as text not as bytes
process = subprocess.Popen(["powershell.exe",file_path], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr = subprocess.STDOUT, shell = True, universal_newlines=True)

# 6 access output from the command line
powershell_communication = process.communicate()[0]

# 7 return the string output as a list, split by new lines with blank values filtered out
credentials_list = list(filter(None,powershell_communication.split('\n')))

#8 replace single space (first occurrence only) with underscore to protect the field names in the upcoming split
protect_credential_field_names = []

for i in credentials_list:
    protect_credential_field_names.append( i.replace(' ','_',1))


#9 create dictionary of credential field names and value in prep for transformation to dataframe
keys = []
values = []

#starting at index value two to exclude name/value and ---- returns from the command line
for i in range(2,len( protect_credential_field_names)):
    #split key value pairs into two separate list elements (ensured by maxsplit = 1) where there is a space
    key_values_list =  protect_credential_field_names[i].split(' ',maxsplit = 1)
    #exclude fields with empty values
    if len(key_values_list) > 1:
        #append field names to the keys list
        keys.append(key_values_list[0])
        #append values to the values list and remove trailing and leading spaces yo
        values.append(key_values_list[1].strip())

#10 return key and value lists as dictionary in prep for final transformation to dataframe
clean_keys = []

#10.1 areplace underscores with spaces and if applicable,remove resulting trainling and leading spaces
for i in keys:
    clean_key = i.replace('_',' ')
    clean_keys.append(clean_key.strip())

#10.2 create dictionary from the clean keys list and the values list
credentials_dictionary = dict(zip(clean_keys,values))

#11 return dictionary inside of a list (this [] resolves scalar value index issue) so you can turn the dictionary into a dataframe
credentials_df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict([credentials_dictionary])

#12 delete temporary powershellscript file
os.remove(file_path)
```

Comment: Why are you using both Python and PowerShell at the same time? Can't you just stick with one scripting language to achieve your desired results? If you must communicate between Python and PowerShell, I recommend something other than string manipulation. Have PowerShell write the output as a JSON string, then use a Python JSON module to parse it back into a usable object.

Comment: @jbsmith thank you it worked!